# Stuck on different keyboard layout at login screen

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support, 21.04

I updated to Ubuntu 21.04 yesterday and prior to updating I had two keyboard layouts, Arabic and English language keyboard layout, by the end of the day I had no use for Arabic layout so I removed it before shutting down the laptop. Now earlier today when I booted up my Ubuntu again, there only seems to be Arabic layout there and no English layout, and my password is in English so I can't type my password and get in and even if I change to console by pressing alt + f2 so I could try to add English language through command somehow, it seems to be typing in Arabic there as well so that doesn't work either, I tried to look around for a fix but I can't seem to find one. I'm pretty inexperienced with many stuff so it'd really be appreciated if someone can help me step by step. Thanks!

P.S - Also I don't know if Arabic staying and English disappearing while I deleted Arabic is because of a bug in 21.04 or a mistake of my own, though I'm pretty sure I deleted Arabic and even made sure before shutting down so it didn't cause me any trouble later on but well it did...

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, had to reinstall Ubuntu using live USB again. The reinstall option was greyed out so I just went ahead selected the 'Something else' option and selected the same mounts as before and deselected the format option. Lost apps but all my documents and stuff remains intact and app data seems to be there too once I reinstall the apps. The keyboard layout was still Arabic once logged in but thankfully it was English on the login screen.